# HTML/JavaScript: How to make default text of a <textarea> undeletable?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

Is there a way to make the default text of a `<textarea>` input become undeletable by the user? For example, if we had a `<textarea>` like this:

`<textarea>I like/dislike this site because</textarea>`

The user should be able to complete the "I like/dislike this site because" sentence but never be able to remove this part.

I understand there are easier approaches for this problem, but I've been asked to do it this way. Also, the target website uses prototype javascript framework so it must either involve prototype or no framework. jQuery cannot be used as it would cause conflict with prototype.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do realize that, no matter what the solution, the user will almost certainly be able to circumvent it by disabling javascript.

Comment: Any reason you can't use a `label` to provide the starter text?

Comment: Yes, I do realize they will be able to circumvent it by disabling javascript, but that will be always added on the server side. I just need a neat way to make it obvious to the user that the sentence will be part of his/her comment.

Comment: This seems like a pretty ridiculous request. Go tell your employer that's he's just shy of retarded for asking for something that's impossible to implement (unless you want to use Flash *shudder*) and pointlessly wasting your time. This "feature" is going to cost hundreds of dollars to implement when they could have just had you use a label or fancy graphic.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer - "Impossible" is a strong word... I think there have been some good suggestions from SO users as to how this could be done. I agree that a label or graphic would be better though.

Comment: @Joshua: I completely agree, but if it's editable text, and the user has the option to disable javascript, all bets are off.

Answer (score 10):

You could make it look like it's part of the textarea, even if it is not.

[Simple jsfiddle example to demonstrate the idea](http://jsfiddle.net/eAW2U/)

Comment: +1. I think this is the best way. Although it's almost the same as having the text outside the box eg. `<p>I like/dislike this site because</p><textarea />`. If the employer dislikes that, he might dislike this solution too.

Answer (score 2):

I would fake it. It's dirty but you cannot delete the default text: http://jsfiddle.net/2EMkF/3/.

```
function $(id) {return document.getElementById(id);}
$('s').addEventListener('click', function() {
    $('t').setSelectionRange(33, 33)
    $('t').focus();
});
$('t').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if($('t').value.substring(0, 33) != ' '.times(33)) {
            $('t').value = ' '.times(Math.max(
                33, $('t').value.firstspace())
            )
            + $('t').value.fromnospaces();
            $('t').setSelectionRange(33,33);
    }
});

function t() {
    if(this.selectionStart < 33) this.setSelectionRange(33,33);
}

$('t').addEventListener('keyup', t);
$('t').addEventListener('click', t);

String.prototype.times = function(n) {
    var r = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) r += this;
    return r;
}

String.prototype.firstspace = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        if(this[i] != ' ')
            return i;
    return -1;
}

String.prototype.fromnospaces = function() {
    return this.substring(this.firstspace());
}
```

Comment: Nice! +1. But aren't you using jQuery?

Comment: Nope, that's my vanilla JavaScript shortcut to `getElementById`. I don't like typing. See the first line of the code.

Comment: @pimvdb +1 for "I don't like typing" :)

Comment: @Kalessin: Hehe, in the end the code has become overcomplicated, too much typing after all...

Answer (score 0):

This code will throw the default text back into the beginning of the text field if it's not present after the user changes it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fixText()
{
    var textAreaElement = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    var searchPhrase = "I like/dislike this site because";
    if(textAreaElement)
    {
        if(textAreaElement.value.indexOf(searchPhrase) != 0)
        {
            textAreaElement.value = searchPhrase + " " + textAreaElement.value
        }
    }
}
</script>

<textarea id="mytextarea" onblur="fixText();" onchange="fixText();">I like/dislike this site because</textarea>
```

I threw this together in just a minute or so, and it has some obvious flaws, such as the fact that if someone only deletes SOME of the default text they might be get a weird result like "I like/dislike this site because I like this site because it's nice". But I'm sure you could manipulate it to make it more effective. Something like this might work in combination with pimvdb's answer.

I like Elian Ebbing's answer though, if your employer will allow you to do it that way.