# Force a textarea input to begin with default text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I have a textarea (or editable DIV) input that I always want to start with default text AND is not editable by the user. So for example:

Textbox would always begin with the default value: `My name is`

Users would be able and required to add their name, such as: `My name is David`

They would not be able to delete the `My name is` default text. Ideally, if the user would click anywhere on that default text, the cursor would jump to the end of that text, so they wouldn't have a chance to even attempt to type something, except after the default. Same goes for backspace, the default text (`My name is`) could not be deleted.

Any suggestions? I have the ability to use Javascript/Jquery.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490410/html-javascript-how-to-make-default-text-of-a-textarea-undeletable

Comment: Any chance that the placeholder attribute could solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stick a label (i.e.: span) right next to the text area and style it so that they look like it's one text area. Just line them up and set a background image (or css borders) behind both of them using css to create the appearance of the text area. Then turn the normal borders off of the textarea also using css. Should be fairly easy to code. Tricky part is just getting it styled correctly. If you don't mind the text being on a different line you could do this (from another post):

http://jsfiddle.net/eAW2U/

Or if you want them on the same line (which would only work for a text box really, not a textarea, you could float them

```
<div style="float:left">etc...
```

Or alternatively you could use the keypress/keyup events to check and see if the keypress will end up changing the beginning of the overall text and if so cancel it.