# How to place a label inside a textarea and make the user type after the label

Tags: html, css

I want to create a textarea-like input (either with a `<textarea>` or a `contentEditable="true"`) with a static text inside undeletable. The value typed by the user have to start just on the right of the static text.

I already have a css/html code doing that, but my solution I have to hardcode a text-indent value on the textarea. How can I do that more dynamically?

Here is a picture of what I want to achieve :
[image: What I want to have]

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>label :</h3>
    <textarea rows="5">Looong text</textarea>
</div>

<style>
    div.container {
    position: relative:
    width: 100%;
}    
h3 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 50px;
}
```

[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/XMENMtlNk5XyKomM4pUN?p=preview)

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Please provide a working demo: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added a plunker link of what I actually did (solution textarea-based)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML/JavaScript: How to make default text of a <textarea> undeletable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490410/html-javascript-how-to-make-default-text-of-a-textarea-undeletable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of a way to add an element/label inside an actual textarea, so I think you will have to use a div with the contenteditable attribute. Look at the snippet below:

```css
.editable-wrapper {
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.label,
.editable { padding: 7px; }

.label {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.editable { min-height: 100px; }
```

```html
<div class="editable-wrapper">
  <span class="label">Your label:</span>
  <div class="editable" contenteditable> </div>
</div>
```

You will probably also need some javascript to retrieve and save the entered data. You could copy the innerHTML of the editable div to an actual (hidden)textarea on form submit or directly post it with ajax on change/keyup.

Comment: It's almost perfect ! The only thing that bother me a little is that the cursor is before "Your label:" when there is no value in the input. Any ideas of how to move it on the right ?
There is no problem for retrieving the content, I'll find a way in my Angular app (maybe just {{ text }} and it will works fine)

Comment: I'm not sure, you could add a space by default. It's not very neat but at least the cursor is in the right position when someone clicks on the editable div.

Comment: I can't use the space character to move the cursor on the right, so I used a special character which looks the same as the space character : Alt + 255 : " "  !

Comment: That's a non-breaking space. You should insert it in your code as html entity `&nbsp;` (or `&#160;`).

Comment: Oh, okay I didn't know it was that element. I tried some things, but I can't just write "&nbsp" or "&#160" because it's not interpreted when Angular render the text. The only way is to use [innerHTML], but I can't do that. I'll let my nbsp character with a comment on the right